# R readline prompt to use in SQL script within R

Tags: sql, r, odbc

I am running a sql script within R. There is a date filter within the script and right now it is hardcoded in. Using the extract I run some analysis, etc. My final goal is to turn this script into Shiny.

I want to be able to make the date filter a prompt using readlines. Does anyone know if I can stick the date in the SQL script using that readline output?

For example:
Readline asks Start date?
Input as 2020-10-01 and gets set as X

The sql code reads:
SELECT * from database
WHERE DATE= 'X'

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## Using Parameterised Query

As pointed out in the comments, using `paste` is unsafe as it leaves the system vulnerable to exploits such as sql injection attacks. This can be mitigated by using parametrised queries, [this is a helpful document for reference](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely#parameterized-queries).

```
 # Get input
r <- readline("Input Date: ")

# Using parameterised Query
sql <- "SELECT * FROM database WHERE DATE = ?"
# Send the paramterised query
query <- DBI::dbSendQuery(conn_string, sql)

# Bind the parameter
DBI::dbBind(query, list(r))
# Fetch Result
DBI::dbFetch(query)
```

You can also use the `sqlInterpolate` if having trouble with parameterised query,

```
query <- 
sqlInterpolate(conn_string, 
               "SELECT * FROM database WHERE DATE = ?date", 
    date = r
)
# Get Results
dbGetQuery(conn_string, query)
```

### Unsafe way

You can use `paste0()` to process the date string using single quotes correctly.

```
# Get input
r <- readline("Input Date: ")
# Paste input with query string noting the use of single quotes '
query <- paste0("SELECT * FROM database WHERE DATE = '", r, "'")
# Make query
dbGetQuery(conn, query)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem! If it answers your question could you mark it as answered please.

Comment: Using `paste` or `sprintf` or similar to encode a user-provided data is bad, for fear of SQL injection. While there are security concerns about malicious [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's a single data analyst running the query. Both `DBI` (with `odbc`) and `RODBC` support parameterized queries, either natively or via add-ons.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for pointing that out, I have updated the answer.

Comment: RStudio's document has not been updated in a bit (imperfect, but it's using hugo-0.26 to render, released Aug 2017), `DBI` now supports binding directly in `dbGetQuery`, something like `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select 1 where 1=?", params=list(0))` (use `list(0)` for no return, effectively `where 1=0`; use `list(1)` to get a return). It's a contrived example, but now I believe the only time one *needs* to use `dbSendQuery` and `dbBind` is if the same query will be bound repeatedly (thereby saving the resultset from the single `dbSendQuery`).